# How access Google Contacts using OpenID in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, oauth, openid

I am using devise to login with omniauth, authid. When the user is logged in I get

```
user_info: 
name: Riccardo Tacconi
last_name: Tacconi
email: email@gmail.com
first_name: Riccardo
uid: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=xxxxxxxxx
provider: google_apps
```

I have found a plug-in: http://stakeventures.com/articles/2009/10/06/portable-contacts-in-ruby to get the Google Contacts. I only need to use this method:

```
@client = PortableContacts::Client.new "http://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people", @access_token
```

but I need a token. I only have the uid. Do you have an idea how to get the access token? There is not any doc about accessing google.

Comment: Duplicate of question? [How access Google Contacts using OpenID in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4337259/128421)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate; in the general case, Signet is the better choice for OAuth, but in this specific case it might not be because of the Portable Contacts support.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this one is fairly complicated.  Pelle's Portable Contacts parser relies on his `oauth` gem.  You might be able to manually construct the [token object](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#AccessToken) (a key/secret pair) from whatever omniauth/authid gives you, but it's likely to be some pretty messy code.

The officially supported OAuth client for Ruby is [Signet](http://signet.rubyforge.org/).  However, Pelle's parser was only designed for use with his OAuth implementation, so again, the story here is about the same.  You might be able to rip out the parsing code from his client and marry it to Signet, but as before, if you go down that route, you've got your work cut out for you.

Probably the easiest thing to do today is to just use the `oauth` gem and accept the dependency tree that Pelle forced on you.

**Edit:** It's awhile later and the `google-api-client` gem may provide you with what you need at this point. Supports both OAuth 1 and 2 and offers discovery-based access to [certain Google APIs](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/SupportedAPIs) in many cases. Unfortunately the Contacts API is not currently on the [list](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/SupportedAPIs) but the client is still capable of making requests to APIs without using discovery, though it's a bit more manual in that case (in that you need to pass it HTTP requests which it will authorize and you're basically on your own for parsing).