# How can I connect to Google using oauth with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oauth

there are oauth and oauth2 gems, but I have not found an example to connect to google with oauth

Comment: Duplicate of [How access Google Contacts using OpenID in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324812/how-access-google-contacts-using-openid-in-ruby)?

Comment: @theTinMan OAuth != OpenID, so may not necessarily be a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 7):

The officially supported method is to use [Signet](http://signet.rubyforge.org/).  The [README](http://signet.rubyforge.org/api/) contains the example code required to authenticate against the Google OAuth endpoints.  See also the [Google API Client for Ruby](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/).  If you have any questions on either, don't hesitate to ping me.  I'm supporting both libraries.

Signet will also work for other OAuth providers. [An official OmniAuth plugin](http://code.google.com/p/omniauth-google/) is also available.

Comment: just out of curiosity, official to whom?  I've never seen that.

Comment: Official, as in, this is the method that Google primarily supports for accessing Google APIs in Ruby. The Google API Client uses Signet as a dependency, it was written by a Googler (me) and it's been through our security review process. Hope that clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Try omniauth instead.

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

Here's An excellent screencast showing how its used:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

Comment: and when I have an openid uid with google how do I extract the user's contancts. I have that one but is useless. I need an oauth object token. There is not a real solution for Ruby using OpenID+Oauth